can't boot linux distro I made
I need some help, because when I boot my initramfs.img and my bzImage in qemu it boots normally. but then it just goes:
[   34.354852] dracut: FATAL: iscsiroot requested but kernel/initrd does not support iscsi
[   34.355624] dracut: Refusing to continue
[   35.141451] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[   35.163823] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
[   35.285640] systemd-journald[86]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
[   35.324915] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
[   35.406544] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.
[   35.441251] (sd-remount)[226]: Remounting '/' read-only with options ''.
[   35.449361] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted.
[   35.451380] systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.
[   35.454930] systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated.
[   35.455640] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
[   35.524419] systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached.
[   35.525318] systemd-shutdown[1]: Stopping MD devices.
[   35.529567] systemd-shutdown[1]: All MD devices stopped.
[   35.530470] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.
[   35.533332] systemd-shutdown[1]: All DM devices detached.
[   35.534460] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems, swaps, loop devices, MD devices and DM devices detached.
[   35.542995] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[   35.549628] systemd-shutdown[1]: Powering off.
[   35.780425] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S5
[   35.782275] reboot: Power down

I've recompiled the kernel with and without iscsi transport, I've remade the initramfs with dracut (with and without iscsi modules). Could someone help me?

What boot parameters are you supplying to the kernel? Or in other words, what is the value of the -append option in your QEMU command line?

it is '-append "root=/home/rio/downloads/rootfs" ' telcoM.

The  -append option for QEMU from the comments:
-append "root=/home/rio/downloads/rootfs"

You are skipping a step.
/home/rio/downloads/rootfs might be a valid path to root filesystem image for QEMU, as it can see the filesystems of the host. But the VM kernel cannot do that at that point. Since the value of root= does not look like any recognizable disk or partition device name, Dracut assumes you are trying to use iSCSI.
You should tell QEMU to present /home/rio/downloads/rootfs as a disk device to the VM, and then change the -append option to tell the VM to use that virtual disk device as the root filesystem.
First, use file /home/rio/downloads/rootfs to see if the rootfs image file contains a partition table or not. Then add a -hda /home/rio/downloads/rootfs option to the QEMU command line, and change the -append option to -append "root=/dev/sda" if there is no partition table in the rootfs image file, or something like -append "root=/dev/sda1" if there is a partition table.
